# Get object and indices from subsetting call

Tags: r, nse

Basically, I would like to create an R function `separate_call` that gets an argument like `x[ind]` and returns `x` and `ind` (so, from the parent environment):

```
x <- 1:10
ind <- 2:3
separate_call(x[ind]) ## should return `list(1:10, 2:3)`
```

I know that I need to use non-standard evaluation and some tree parsing but I'm not familiar enough with these two concepts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the solution to be literally `list(1:10, 2:3)` as symbol or as a character "list(1:10,2:3)" or   
`$x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$ind
[1] 2 3`

Comment: The last one (numbers). I found a solution. If you have a better solution, please add it.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code of `pryr:::tree` and experimenting a little bit, I found a solution:

```
separate_call <- function(call) {
  call.sep <- as.list(substitute(call))
  parent_env <- parent.frame()
  x   <- eval(call.sep[[2]], parent_env)
  ind <- eval(call.sep[[3]], parent_env)
  list(x, ind)
}
```

Verification:

```
> x <- 1:10
> ind <- 2:3
> separate_call(x[ind])
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

> separate_call(x[1:2])
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: Seems like `as.list` is not even needed.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this solution, not very elegant, see if this fits your need.

```
separate_call <- function(m){
    dprse <- deparse(substitute(m)) ##deparsing the data: to make it as string
    lyst <- strsplit(dprse,"\\[|\\]")[[1]] ##removing the square brackets to sparate contents of m
    lapply(lyst, function(y)eval(parse(text = y), envir = parent.frame()))

}
```

I hope this works, I tried it by calling it in three different ways

```
separate_call(1:10[ind])
separate_call(x[2:3])
separate_call(1:10[2:3])
```

They all gave me same response

```
> separate_call(1:10[ind])
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

> separate_call(x[2:3])
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

> separate_call(1:10[2:3])
[[1]]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `get` won't work if you specify directly `2:3` instead of `ind`.

Comment: You should add the environment to the eval call (imagine you have `lyst <- x; separate_call(lyst[ind])`. In any case, I thing my current solution would be more robust than using regular expressions.